# Excel Find & Replace Tool

Tags: excel, cell, replace

I am trying to fix a bunch of email addresses that I have in an excel file.  For some reason, in the past, some import routine decided to slice off some email addresses that were too long or somehow, the last letter was removed.  This is for our company newsletter list.

So I have 100's of emails in my list that end in .ne or .co or .or instead of .net, .com, or .org.

I can use Excel's replace utility to find broken emails by using the search term of *.ne and selecting find exact matches only.

But when I indicate I want to replace that found item with *.net, the actual content of the offender is replaced with that: *.net instead of the first portion of the email address.

Is there any function or can I use that tool to find and replace in this scenario?

Regards;
Ricky

Comment: did you find your answer in one of the below answers?

Comment: It is an interesting selection of approaches ... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just wrote this macro and tested it on three different email addresses ending in .com, .net, and .org. There is no error-checking and this macro assumes that the email addresses are somewhere within the columns A-Z. It might also try and append an 'm', 't', or 'g' to other data matching the ".co" etc. criteria.

This macro basically scans for cells between A1 and Z30000 (as you mentioned you had a number of addresses) and looks for anything ending in .co .ne or .or. It appends the proper letter to make the address 'complete'. I hope this helps.

```
Sub Fix_Email()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rngEmail As Range
Set rngEmail = Range("A1:A30000")

For i = 1 To 30000

   'Checks to see if the last 3 characters of a cell's value end in .co, .ne, or .or

    If Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 3) = ".co" Then
        rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "m"

    ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 3) = ".ne" Then
        rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "t"

    ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 3) = ".or" Then
        rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "g"

    ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 2) = ".c" Then 
        rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "om" 

    ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 2) = ".n" Then 
        rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "et"

    ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 2) = ".o" Then
        rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "rg"

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, this breezed through 30000 records like nobody's business.  Quick and did it but it only worked when I changed the range from A1:z30000 to A1:A40000.  Maybe it did work the other way round, but was just taking too long to process.

Comment: Perfect. I defined a larger range because I wasn't sure where in your spreadsheet the email addresses were kept, but most importantly I'm glad it worked!

Comment: If it was truncating down to .c, .n, and .o you could add the following to fix those as well:

`code` 
ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 2) = ".c" Then
rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "om"
ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 2) = ".n" Then
rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "et"
ElseIf Right(rngEmail(i).Value, 2) = ".o" Then
rngEmail(i).Value = rngEmail(i).Value & "rg"

This would go before the End If statement.

Answer (score 4):

just need to loop through the cells and split it out on the '.' then check the last element in the variant array for the correct term.  Somthing along these lines.

```
Sub fixEmails()
ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Cells
Dim v As Variant
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
    v = Split(cell.Value, ".")
        If v(UBound(v)) = "ne" Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value + "t"
        Else
            If v(UBound(v)) = "co" Then
                cell.Value = cell.Value + "m"
            Else
                If v(UBound(v)) = "or" Then
                    cell.Value = cell.Value + "g"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this could definately work too, but I didn't try it.  From looking at it, I think it would be faster than the other answer since it's not traversing empty cells.  I'm not sure what the Dim C as Range line is for though.

Comment: Dim c as Range was a typo and has been removed. @pnuts doesnt matter what is before the @ sign as the Top Level Domain extension should be the last element in the variant array. - not real happy that the guy who posted after me got the answer...typical of this site

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, where the OP gets to choose the best answer -- for whatever reason.  If you take point-scoring too seriously, it will be less fun and less profitable.  StackOverflow tests your communication skills and patience, as well as your technical savvy.

Comment: @smandoli He choose the answer at the top, its a problem with this site and how it display's the order of the answers. You should know this.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding a column that uses a formula to display the needed letter.  Then use one more column to concatenate.  Then do a big "paste values" onto the original column.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)=".ne", "t",IF(RIGHT(A1,3)=".co", "m",""))
```

This gives you the idea.  Let column A be your emails, and you've handled `net` and `com`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I have about 25000 emails and not all of them have the issue.  As well, some need a t, others need a m or g for net, com or org.

Comment: This is still very simple.  You will use an IF statement to analyze the last four characters of the email field and display the needed character -- or no character, if criteria not met.

Comment: Ok, I think that might work, using the if statement in the column next to it.  Since the macro only partly worked, I will try with this.  The macro solution wouldn't replace items with only a .c or .n or .o, but did work on .co or .ne or .or.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply when using find and replace in Excel you don't need to use a wildcard. If you run find '.ne' and replace with '.net' and so on for '.co' and '.or' this will work.

However you may face another problem where email addresses may have .ne, .co or .or appearing earlier.

To avoid this I would expand on Smandoli's solution and use the following function alongside your email addresses:

`=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)=".ne", A1&"t",IF(RIGHT(A1,3)=".co", A1&"m",IF(RIGHT(A1,3)=".or",A1&"g",A1)))`

And then copy and paste values the column afterwards.

Comment: finding just by using '.ne' will not work as it will find all occurrences of '.ne' even if it is '.net'.  The reason I had to use the wildcard was because I had to select "match entire word" option.  This limits the results to only those emails that end in .ne or .co or .or

Comment: I see, overlooked that possibility!!

Answer (score 1):

To give more details if A is the column of the email address you set up column B as:
=IF(RIGHT(A3,2)="co","m", IF(RIGHT(A3,2)="ne", "t", IF(RIGHT(A3,2)="or", "g")))

And column C as
=CONCATENATE(A3,B3)

Answer (score 0):

For this type of task, looping over cells is inherintly quite slow.  Using a variant array is *much* faster

```
Sub email()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set rng = Range([A1], [A1].End(xlDown)) ' assuming no blank cells in the list
    v = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        Select Case Right(v(i, 1), 3)
            Case ".co"
                v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & "m"
            Case ".ne"
                v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & "t"
            Case ".or"
                v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & "g"
        End Select
    Next
    rng = v
End Sub
```

executes in < 0.5 sec on ~60,000 rows